# How to properly hide a sliding menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I have the following menu:

```
<div id="menuItem">Item1</div>

<div id="subMenu">
<ul>
    <li>subitem1</li>    
    <li>subitem2</li>    
    <li>subitem3</li>    
</ul>
</div>
​
```

Animated like this:

```
$('#menuItem').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#subMenu').slideDown(400);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#subMenu').hide(400);
});
​
```

Unfortunately, as the mouse leave the submenu, the submenu dissapears. How do I make the submenu only disapears when the mouse leave the menuitem OR the submenu list ? I would like to be able to hover the mouse on the submenu. Notice that there is a gap bewteen the two menus.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dSWQM/)

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but the Jquery Accordion have you considered the jquery accordion? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-jquery-accordion/

Comment: Not a full answer, but I think it will help you. You might want to check out the hoverIntent jQuery plugin. For situations like you describe it gives the user some lattitude in moving the mouse out of an area when you are hiding something like a menu and makes it more user friendly.

Comment: My menu has to be slicing as in the jsFiddle example. I want to know a way of hiding it as I explained.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by slicing. does the html-structure have to stay that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wanted to keep the **exact same html structure**, you could use the following code:

```
$('#menuItem').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#subMenu').slideDown(400);
}).next('#subMenu').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#subMenu').hide(400);
});
```

Notice that I've told jQuery to hide the `#subMenu` only when the mouse has left the `#subMenu`.

Answer (score 3):

make the sub-menu actually "inside" the menu-item you are attaching the event to, this way the in/out event only happen when the user actually *leaves* the menu area

like this:

**css**

```
#menuItem {

 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
}

#menuItem .title {
    background-color: orange; 
}

#subMenu {
 background-color: grey;
 margin-top: 5px;   
 cursor: pointer;
 display:none;
 width: 80px;
}​
```

**html**

```
 <div id="menuItem">
    <div class="title">Item1</div>
    <div id="subMenu">
        <ul>
            <li>subitem1</li>    
            <li>subitem2</li>    
            <li>subitem3</li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​
```

**js**

```
$('#menuItem').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#subMenu').slideDown(400);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#subMenu').hide(400);
});
```

***friendly note:***

you might want to use some form of `.stop(true, true)` prior to animating the menu, or else moving a cursor back and forth rapidly over the menu will cause the animations to "stack" and it will just feel strange to the user.  see discussion here: [Where to put clearQueue in jQuery code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365205/where-to-put-clearqueue-in-jquery-code/9365372#9365372)

*so it would look like this:*

```
$('#menuItem').hover(function() {
  $('#subMenu').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    $('#subMenu').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div id="menuItem">Item1
   <div id="subMenu">
      <ul>
          <li>subitem1</li>    
          <li>subitem2</li>    
          <li>subitem3</li>    
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

This works in my browser (firefox)

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to have the Menu and Sub Menu inside the same container so you don't need to have a separate mouse handler when navigating sub menu.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dSWQM/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="subMenu">
<div id="menuItem">Item1</div>
<ul>
    <li>subitem1</li>    
    <li>subitem2</li>    
    <li>subitem3</li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#subMenu').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#subMenu ul').slideDown(400);
    isInsideSubMenu = true;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#subMenu ul').hide(400);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#subMenu ul { display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you don't want to have the submenu inside menuitem (which could mess with your CSS, you can wrap everything in a parent div like:

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="menuItem">Item1</div>
    <div id="subMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>subitem1</li>    
        <li>subitem2</li>    
        <li>subitem3</li>    
    </ul>
    </div>
​</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$('#all').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#subMenu').slideDown(400);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#subMenu').hide(400);
});
```

​